# C# Dynamic List Class

Tags: c#

I have a bit of a weird issue. Working in **C#** script with **SSIS** I have developed a need to build a List based off Dynamic Data.

> Background

To explain it, a script task is fired that has a variable API URL, this goes off and pulls a JSON string back and then throws it into a strongly typed list using the following code.

```
 var listobject = get_APIData<ApplicationOneDataSet>(url)
```

The class that does this is long winded and not really needed in the context of this issue.
**ApplicationOneDataSet** is a strongly typed match to one of the possible JSON results returned by `get_APIData`.

Now I have a need to change **ApplicationOneDataSet** to **ApplicationTwoDataSet** dynamically based on which API URL I pass to the script.

So what I have done is send through a second variable to the script called class name which contains the string "ApplicationDataSetOne" or "ApplicationDataSetTwo" based on which context I call it under.

> The Question

My question is how can I dynamically vary this line:

```
var listobject = get_APIData<ApplicationOneDataSet>(url)
```

With the string variable passed into the script.

My original thinking was something along the lines of this:

```
 var ClassType = (string) Dts.Variables["AppClassName"].Value;
 Type type = Type.GetType(ClassType);
 var listobject = get_APIData<type>(url)
```

Though it doesn't seem to like that. Any tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is exactly two types you can use and you know them at compile time, I would not look further than a simple `if`. It works, it's easy, everyone understands it.

You *can* do it totally dynamic at runtime, but that's a huge pain in the... where you don't want it to be. If you really want to go down that rabbit hole, you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method).

Comment: I like your solution, in the Dev the if would do it, but eventually it would need to be completely dynamic based on the class. I have some reading to do thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood what you are trying to do, but how about writing an interface ApplicationDataSet and then making a list of it? This way your list is going to be able to contain both types of data.